# What will we happened when we move data from ax into a port address

Tags: c++, assembly, io, x86, port

for loading a frequency into the counter register of a 8254 chip , we load the frequency into ax and then we move al and ah one by one into the port#42h:

```
    mov ax,1fb4h
    out 42h,al
    mov al,Ah
    out 42h,AL
```

Okay , Why it works ?I think there is an overwrite and the last value of port 42h will be AH =>1f , so never b4 (they lower bits) will be kept in the port address !
So we will loose the frequency ...

Why we cannot use this :

```
out 42h,AX
```

if port address space is less than AX , so why the first lines of code works and how ?

Comment: why your finger jumps on close button ? is it tired ?

Comment: Look at the [pinout of the Intel 8254](http://download.intel.com/design/archives/periphrl/docs/23124406.pdf) and ask yourself why it isn't accepting 16-bit data. Not that hard to understand!

Answer (score 5):

`out port,ax` will try to write to a 16-bit port. The 8254 doesn't provide a 16-bit port -- only 8-bit ports.

I haven't verified, but I believe if you did a 16-bit write to port 42, the low byte would go to port 42, and the high byte to port 43. You *really* don't want that though, because port 43 is the PITs command/mode register.

As for why/how it does work: internally the PIT has a 16-bit register, but provides only an 8-bit port to access it. When you do the first write, the PIT temporarily latches it. When you do the second write, the PIT latches that as well, then writes the 16-bits from the latch to the register.

Comment: you mean if we use "out port,ax" , port 42 has the al and port 43 has the ah ? and by using 4 lines of code we won't set PIT ?

Comment: Yes, if you tried to do a single 16-bit write, I believe al would get written to 42h and ah to 43h.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: so by 4 lines of code we will set PIT ? not 42h? I mean we will do something like this : copy port42,al and immediately copy port42,ah .... So what will happend , I think the frequency will be crashed and missed it's lower bits.

Comment: Port 42h (on a PC) maps to one of the PIT's registers. You can't write AH directly to a port: there's simply no instruction for that. The available choices are AL and AX (and to write AX, you have to specify the port number in DX, not as an immediate).